# How do I render a nested data structure with Node.js/Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

In my .js file I have the following data structure

```
var menu = { "Sport":"Racing",
    "Region":{
        "AUS":{ "name":"APrk", "key":"1234" },
        "GB":{ "name":"Cran", "key":"5678" }
    }
};
res.render('layout.jade', {locals: {menu: menu}});
```

In my layout.jade I have the following

```
for item in menu
  p= item
```

This produces the following output

> Racing
>
> [object Object]

Which is on the right track.  What I would like to know is how can I access the nested structures?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this

```
// layout.jade
each value, key in locals.menu
  // may nest more iteration
  each v, k in value
```

Iteration of object key/value does not grantee order. You may want to use array.

Details: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a9